# How to set drop down list control in Word document using c#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, novacode-docx

I am having issues with setting a drop down list control in ms word document using Novacode-Docx. e.g. Gender from drop down list.
I have got some text replacement but that's easy. I have done that. Just the drop down list I am struggling with.
If there is any solution in c# other than using Novacode-Docx I am happy to implement that.
I haven't included any code for the reason that I don't know how to set or get the drop down list values from Ms word document using c#. I have tried google but didn't get any thing related to drop down list.
Here is a sample DropDown.
I have used Drop down list from Developer option and used the properties to add items to it.
[image]

[image]

Here is the actual List

Comment: Since we don't know what *kind* of dropdown this is it's not possible to give you any direction. I can think of at least three different kinds (and there might be more) of dropdown available in the Word UI...

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your comment. I have updated the the question with sample DropDown list.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't tell us what kind of dropdown list this is. If you don't know the techy-term could you tell us which commands you use to create it in the Word document?

Comment: @CindyMeister I have updated the question. I have used Deleoper tab and then drop down list and then used properties for adding item.

Answer (score 1):

To access the list of a content control dropdown use the `Add` method. I have no idea whether the library you're using provides access to that. The following code sample is standard C#:

```
object oLstEntryValue = "1";
object oLstEntryIndex = 1;
ContentControl.DropdownListEntries.Add("entry caption", ref oLstEntryValue, ref oLstEntryIndex);
```

The last two parameters are optional, so you can also pass Type.Missing if you don't want/need to specify them.

Comment: I have tried but the library i am using is not providing access to this. Is it possible if you can please create an example using any librarly that works.

Comment: You said plain old C# would be OK. My code is exactly that. All you need to do is, as always, set a reference to the Microsoft Word library, from the COM tab in the dialog box for binding in outside libraries.

Comment: I have tried all my best to use you code for last 3 weeks but couldn't make it work due to my lack of knowledge. can you please write a complete code that select a value of the drop down list.